# color category in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, colors, histogram

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wi3B.png)
I want to plot histogram using d3.js where i have dataset of around 13000 points which is divided into 2 clusters . I want to color both of them but when i use category color it only shows first one.In the input file i have Droplet_no, Amplitude, Cluster.

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    d3.csv("test_F06.csv",function type(d){
            d.Droplet_no = +d.Droplet_no;
            d.Amplitude = +d.Amplitude;
            return d;} , function(data){

            var width = 600;
            height = 500;
            padding = 50;
            var colorColumn = "Cluster";


            var map = data.map(function(i){return parseInt(i.Amplitude);})

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(map)])
               .range([0, width]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x);


            var numbins = 3000;
            var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
            .bins(x.ticks(numbins))
            (map);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(histogram.map(function(i){return i.length;}))])
                    .range([0, height/2]);

                    var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();


                 var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width+padding)
                .attr("height", height+ padding)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")

                var bars = canvas.selectAll(".bar")
                   .data(histogram)
                   .enter()
                   .append("g")
                   .attr("class", "bar")

                 var group = canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("tansform","translate(0, " + height + ")")

                   bars.append("rect")
                        .attr("x", function(d){return x(d.x);})
                        .attr("y", function(d){return 500-y(d.y);})
                        .attr("width", function(d){return d.dx;})
                        .attr("height", function(d){ return y(d.y);})
                        .attr("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d[colorColumn]);});

                    })

</script>
```

Can anyone help me?
I am attaching image of the plot as well

Comment: `category10()` is an ordinal scale.

Comment: Can you give me an idea how can i proceed?

Comment: Yes, sure, but first explain me what is `colorColumn` is and where is the attached image.

Comment: Image is at the top of the post and colorColumn is simply a variable where i load categorial colors .

Comment: sample data of the input csv file as follows : Droplet_no,Amplitude,Cluster
1,1209.93616,1
2,1241.489,1
3,1267.435,1
4,1273.78552,1
5,1278.0188,1
6,1284.31763,1
7,1285.1134,1

Comment: So, is `colorColumn` always "Cluster"?

Comment: yeah...you can consider cluster as a ordinal variable because number of it takes value either 0 or 1

Comment: Wait a minute, now I'm confused. Cluster is not a variable, colorColumn is. And it has always one value, which is cluster. So, your domain has always one value.

Comment: Ca you mail me ...I will send you my data file so that you may check..mail id :shubh8794@gmail.com

Comment: Don't worry, we can solve this here. Just now I see that you have Cluster in your CVS, I've missed that. So, moving on, next step: set the domain of `colorScale`, with all possible values of Cluster: `colorScale.domain([0, 1])`.

Comment: Well, I don't know what's happening in your code. I just mocked up this fiddle with a data just like yours, and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/g6o6vh7w/1/ . Try to make a fiddle or a plunker, it will be easier to someone else helping you.